# Display list in JSP using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to display all rows from the database table by their primary key(catCodes) but I get the NullPointerException error. I am able to display one row by specifying the primary key but having trouble displaying all the rows.

JSP:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped-rows table-bordered table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Category Description</b></td>
                            <td><b>Category Audit Date</b></td>
                            <td><b>Category Audit Location</b></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${eligCatsForm.eligCats}">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <c:out value="${listValue.catDesc}" /> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <c:out value="${listValue.catAuditDate}" /> 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <c:out value="${listValue.catAuditLocation}" /> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
```

Controller:

```
@ActionID(action = ActionTypes.NO_LOG)
@RequestMapping(value ="displayEligCats",method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_EMS_NOTE_VIEWER','ROLE_EMS_NOTE_USER','ROLE_EMS_NOTE_UPDATE_USER')")
public String displayEligCats(@RequestParam(value="catCode", required=false) Long catCode, Model model) {

    try {

    List<EligibilityCategories> eligCats = eligibilityCategoriesService.getEligCats(catCode);
    EligibilityCategoriesForm eligCatsForm = new EligibilityCategoriesForm ();
    eligCatsForm.setEligCats(eligCats);

    model.addAttribute("eligCatsForm", eligCatsForm);

    logger.debug("Exiting AdminReviewController.displayEligNotes");
    return WebConstants.RETURN_ELIG_CATS;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if(logger.isErrorEnabled())
        {
            logger.error(e);
        }
        throw new ErrorException(e.getMessage());
    }   
}
```

Service:

```
public interface EligibilityCategoriesService {
List<EligibilityCategories> getEligCats(long catCode);
```

}

ServiceImpl:

```
@Service("eligibilityCategories")
public class EligibilityCategoriesServiceImpl implements                     EligibilityCategoriesService {

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@Autowired
EligibilityCategoriesDao eligCatsDao;

@Autowired
private CoreDao coreDao;

@Override
public List<EligibilityCategories> getEligCats(long catCode) {
    return eligCatsDao.getEligCats(catCode);

}
```

}

DAO:

```
public interface EligibilityCategoriesDao {
final static String FIND_ELIG_CATS_BY_CAT_CODE = "EligibilityCategories.findEligCatsByCatCode";

List<EligibilityCategories> getEligCats(long catCode);
```

}

JPA DAO:

```
@Repository
public class JPAEligibilityCategoriesDao implements EligibilityCategoriesDao {

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "emf")
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public List<EligibilityCategories> getEligCats(long catCode) {
    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(FIND_ELIG_CATS_BY_CAT_CODE);
    query.setParameter(QueryParameterConstants.QPC_CAT_CODE, catCode);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<EligibilityCategories> eligCats = (List<EligibilityCategories>) query.getResultList();
    return eligCats;
}
```

}

Form:

```
public class EligibilityCategoriesForm {

private Long catCode;
private List<EligibilityCategories> eligCats;

public Long getCatCode() {
    return catCode;
}

public void setCatCode(Long catCode) {
    this.catCode = catCode;
}

public List<EligibilityCategories> getEligCats() {
    return eligCats;
}

public void setEligCats(List<EligibilityCategories> eligCats) {
    this.eligCats = eligCats;
}
```

}

Domain:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TSEM_ELIG_CATS")
public class EligibilityCategories implements java.io.Serializable {
private long catCode;
private String catDesc;
private Integer catVerNum;
private Long catAuditUser;
private Date catAuditDate;
private String catAuditAction;
private String catAuditLocation;

public EligibilityCategories() {
}

public EligibilityCategories(long catCode, String catDesc, Integer catVerNum, 
        Long catAuditUser, Date catAuditDate, String catAuditAction, 
        String catAuditLocation) {
    this.catCode = catCode;
    this.catDesc = catDesc;
    this.catVerNum = catVerNum;
    this.catAuditUser = catAuditUser;
    this.catAuditDate = catAuditDate;
    this.catAuditAction = catAuditAction;
    this.catAuditLocation = catAuditLocation;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "CAT_CODE", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
public long getCatCode() {
    return this.catCode;
}

public void setCatCode(long catCode) {
    this.catCode = catCode;
}

@Column(name = "CAT_DESC", nullable = false, length = 2000)
public String getCatDesc() {
    return this.catDesc;
}

public void setCatDesc(String catDesc) {
    this.catDesc = catDesc;
}

@Column(name = "CAT_VER_NUM", precision = 5, scale = 0)
public Integer getCatVerNum() {
    return this.catVerNum;
}

public void setCatVerNum(Integer catVerNum) {
    this.catVerNum = catVerNum;
}

@Column(name = "CAT_AUDIT_USER", precision = 10, scale = 0)
public Long getCatAuditUser() {
    return this.catAuditUser;
}

public void setCatAuditUser(Long catAuditUser) {
    this.catAuditUser = catAuditUser;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "CAT_AUDIT_DATE", length = 7)
public Date getCatAuditDate() {
    return this.catAuditDate;
}

public void setCatAuditDate(Date catAuditDate) {
    this.catAuditDate = catAuditDate;
}

@Column(name = "CAT_AUDIT_ACTION", length = 1)
public String getCatAuditAction() {
    return this.catAuditAction;
}

public void setCatAuditAction(String catAuditAction) {
    this.catAuditAction = catAuditAction;
}

@Column(name = "CAT_AUDIT_LOCATION", length = 20)
public String getCatAuditLocation() {
    return this.catAuditLocation;
}

public void setCatAuditLocation(String catAuditLocation) {
    this.catAuditLocation = catAuditLocation;
}
```

}

Any advice would be very helpful. I am new to java and Spring so please don't laugh.

Comment: Please edit your question and include exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You declared the parameter `catCode` as primitive type long:

```
getEligCats(long catCode);
```

But in the `Controller` class the parameter `catCode` is declared as `Long` object.

When you call `displayEligCats` to get "all categories" without specify any catCode, its parameter will be `null` and it cannot be "casted" to primitive type long.

Change the signature of method definition in service and dao like:

```
getEligCats(Long catCode);
```

And be careful to check for `null` value of catCode parameter.

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error but still not displaying the results just a blank table. I also put in the check for null value. Any ideas?

Comment: You have to check what happens when query is executed, probably the issue is there. Controller and View seems to be ok, post the SQL command, may be you're still adding the filter parameter when `catCode` is null?